# Efficient operator< with multiple members

Tags: c++, performance

Suppose a class has multiple members relevant to the objects' order, e.g., `A { T1 x; T2 y; };`.
The standard implementation of `operator<` I know is

```
bool A::operator<(const A& a) {
  return x < a.x || (x == a.x && y < a.y);
}
```

But that looks horribly inefficient to me, especially when `T1` is `std::vector`. (It's even inefficient to read and maintain when there are more members.)

Is there a "standard" *C++-way* of comparing things efficiently? Or does everyone go her own way like so:

```
enum Cmp = {LESS,EQUAL,GREATER}
Cmp A::CompareTo(const A& a) {
  const Cmp c1 = x.CompareTo(a.x);
  if (c1 != EQUAL) return c1;
  const Cmp c2 = y.CompareTo(a.y);
  return c2;
}
```

And for `std::vector` one would perhaps use `std::mismatch` to implement such a `CompareTo`?

(I'm sure that's not a new question, but `operator<` is a bad search term.)

Comment: Have you actually measured to determine that it is inefficient?

Comment: The best thing you can do is compare the fields that are most likely to vary first. You may have to do some profiling and analysis to determine this for complex data sets. Also for fields that may have more expensive comparisons (e.g. strings or other objects), prefer to compare them last. Profiling will help identify bottlenecks here as well. Of course, ordering constraints may limit your options. However, be sure your `operator <` is actually a relevant bottleneck before you go optimizing it; the *best* way to implement it is the way that is clearest and easily maintainable as possible.

Comment: @TimoGeusch: Reading all 10000 elements of both vectors twice, because they are equal? Sure that's inefficient.

Comment: @JasonC I don't think that's a solution. (1) There may be an order to that class which `operator<` should respect. (2) The "standard" way to implement `operator<` isn't even very maintainable, I think, compared to the second solution. (You disagree?) In general I of course agree to first profile and then optimize.

Comment: @chs Why do you think the first is the "standard" way? The standard way, if some exists, is using ties (see my answer), at least since 2011.

Comment: @chs 1) Yes; that is the big constraint (that's what I meant by "ordering constraints may limit your option", but I can only fit so much in a comment). 2) I do disagree that the usual way isn't very maintainable, but I'm also used to seeing that way so it looks familiar to me at this point. There isn't *really* a "better way", unfortunately, anything else you come up with will just be some form of that same "check one field, then the next, and so on".

Comment: @leemes Ties are great but just remember that they're just one of many forms of the same general technique of comparing one value, then the next, etc. You can't really avoid it. There would be no real performance impact to ties - under the hood they do the same thing.

Comment: @JasonC We just talked about the maintainability, didn't we? ;) And I find it very much more maintainable as well as readable to use ties instead of hand-crafted lexi comparison. In my answer, I tell that the order can be changed if you didn't make any assumptions about them. Otherwise I agree: it's already the best you can do.

Comment: @leemes It would be silly to argue against the clarity and maintainability of ties!

Comment: @JasonC To put it precise: My answer addresses both efficiency and maintainability (in that order, and the question asks about efficiency but complains about the maintainability, too, and I don't like partial answers, so I addressed that too). My comment just addressed your point when you said that lexi comparison can't be any more maintainable than in OP's code, which I strongly disagree with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your type has two (or more) members, which should be compared *lexicographically*, you typically already have an order in your mind in which the members should be compared (i.e. their "priority", for example first the "last name" then the "first name" for sorting persons in an address list).

- If you have such a fixed order, you have to check them in this order (the other members aren't of any interest if the first are not equal, so you first need to compare the first member).
- If you don't need a specific order, then choose some efficient order: put those members first which are fast to compare, and put the slow ones at the end, e.g. the vectors.

Then, after you found the "efficient" order of your members (here, let's say `x` and `y`), to lexicographically compare two objects, use a **tuple** constructed with `std::tie`, which is easily extendable to more than two members. And please overload the operator as a non-member.

```
bool operator<(const A& a, const A& b) {
    return std::tie(a.x, a.y)
         < std::tie(b.x, b.y);
}
```

If you're stuck with a pre-C++11 compiler (or one that doesn't support tuples), you can use boost's equivalent.

Comment: Ties are very clean. I think this answer could benefit if you elaborate more on how their usage, compared to the OP's example, is related to "efficiency", though, since that was the root of the question (as I read it anyways).

Comment: I was taking about the efficiency before. The ties are just a more maintainable version of OP's first example, as he also complained about its maintainability.

Comment: That looks very nice (concerning readability)! Didn't know that. I played around with it a bit and it seems like is no penalty (no additional copies) over what I called the "standard" way above.

Comment: Exactly; it's zero overhead and much more maintainable, that's why it's strongly recommended since C++11 when tuples were introduced.